# cxf bouncycastle collision in camel application

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf, bouncycastle

I am using camel and cxf in an application. There is a new module which has bouncycastle dependency `org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.53`. After adding this module, I started to get Exceptions in runtime:

```
21-Dec-2015 12:02:06.194 INFO [Camel (camel-1) thread #17 - seda://sp-tsm:handleEndServiceChangeNotification] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.PBEPKCS12$AlgParams]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.PBEPKCS12$AlgParams]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1335)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1321)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1203)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1636)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1592)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695)
    at java.security.AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(AlgorithmParameters.java:146)
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.decodeParams(AlgorithmId.java:121)
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.<init>(AlgorithmId.java:114)
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.parse(AlgorithmId.java:372)
    at sun.security.pkcs.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.<init>(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:80)
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:321)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1023)
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin.getPrivateKey(Merlin.java:766)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:555)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.action.SignatureAction.execute(SignatureAction.java:152)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.handler.WSHandler.doSenderAction(WSHandler.java:237)
    at com.toro.wm.protocol.gpm.ws.interceptor.WSS4JOutCustomInterceptor.access$200(WSS4JOutCustomInterceptor.java:56)
    at com.toro.wm.protocol.gpm.ws.interceptor.WSS4JOutCustomInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JOutCustomInterceptor.java:284)
    at com.toro.wm.protocol.gpm.ws.interceptor.WSS4JOutCustomInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(WSS4JOutCustomInterceptor.java:156)
    at com.toro.wm.protocol.gpm.ws.interceptor.WSS4JOutCustomInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(WSS4JOutCustomInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:516)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:425)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfProducer.process(CxfProducer.java:153)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.SynchronousDelegateProducer.process(SynchronousDelegateProducer.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:129)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.sendToConsumers(SedaConsumer.java:291)
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.doRun(SedaConsumer.java:200)
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.run(SedaConsumer.java:147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and

```
10:21:53.919 [Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - seda://sp-tsm:checkGlobalEligibility] ERROR c.t.w.c.r.ExceptionHandlingRoutes - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: org.globalplatform.namespaces.systems_messaging._2_1.CheckGlobalEligibilityRequestType, Body: org.globalplatform.namespaces.systems_messaging._2_1.CheckGlobalEligibilityRequestType@29f83af2, CaughtExceptionType: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault, 
CaughtExceptionMessage: Security processing failed., 
StackTrace: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Security processing failed.        
    at com.toro.wm.protocol.gpm.ws.interceptor.WSS4JOutCustomInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JOutCustomInterceptor.java:292)
    at com.toro.wm.protocol.gpm.ws.interceptor.WSS4JOutCustomInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(WSS4JOutCustomInterceptor.java:156)
    at com.toro.wm.protocol.gpm.ws.interceptor.WSS4JOutCustomInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(WSS4JOutCustomInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:516)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:418)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfProducer.process(CxfProducer.java:116)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:129)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.sendToConsumers(SedaConsumer.java:291)
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.doRun(SedaConsumer.java:200)
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.run(SedaConsumer.java:147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Cannot create Crypto class org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin
Original Exception was org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Failed to load credentials.
Original Exception was java.io.IOException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.CryptoFactory.getInstance(CryptoFactory.java:134)
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.CryptoFactory.getInstance(CryptoFactory.java:203)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JUtils.loadCryptoFromPropertiesFile(WSS4JUtils.java:350)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.AbstractWSS4JInterceptor.loadCryptoFromPropertiesFile(AbstractWSS4JInterceptor.java:207)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.handler.WSHandler.loadCrypto(WSHandler.java:1096)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.handler.WSHandler.loadSignatureCrypto(WSHandler.java:990)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.handler.WSHandler.doSenderAction(WSHandler.java:142)
    at com.toro.wm.protocol.gpm.ws.interceptor.WSS4JOutCustomInterceptor.access$200(WSS4JOutCustomInterceptor.java:56)
    at com.toro.wm.protocol.gpm.ws.interceptor.WSS4JOutCustomInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JOutCustomInterceptor.java:284)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Failed to load credentials.
Original Exception was java.io.IOException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin.load(Merlin.java:409)
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin.loadProperties(Merlin.java:225)
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin.<init>(Merlin.java:161)
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.CryptoFactory.getInstance(CryptoFactory.java:129)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1978)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin.load(Merlin.java:403)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher$BufferedGenericBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1969)
    ... 32 more
```

Bouncycastle is not used anywhere else in the application. CXF version is 3.0.6.
So it seems that CXF and bouncycastle don't work well together somehow (at least in my case). How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

According to this thread [problem with loading Bouncy Castle](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.tomcat.user/216495) it seems to be a permission issue, since you should install your Crypto providers into a specific directory:

> Crypto providers need to be installed into the JRE extension directory
>   (e.g. $JRE_HOME/lib/ext) and an entry must be added to
>   $JRE_HOME/lib/security/java.security to install the provider.  For
>   example:
>
> security.provider.5=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider